# Como recuperar informações de um httpOptions em outro componente Angular?

Tags: angular, api

Basicamente tenho um componente `user-login-component` e nele tenho a seguinte função:

```
userLogin() {
    this.restApi.auth(this.userDetails).subscribe(dados => {
      var headers_object = new HttpHeaders();
      headers_object.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
      headers_object.append("X-token", "Basic" + dados);

      const httpOptions = {
        headers: headers_object
      };

      this.router.navigate(["main-page"]);
    });
  }
```

Sendo que no `restApi.auth` tenho:

```
auth(user): Observable<User> {
    return this.http
      .post<User>(this.apiURL + "/auth", JSON.stringify(user), this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map(user => {
          // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
          if (user && user.token) {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(user));
            this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
          }
          return user;
        })
      );
  }
```

Ela funciona e só faz login caso exista um cadastro.

O Problema é que não consegui utilizar no component `main-page` algo afim de recuperar o user.

Também sei que na página `main-page` tenho acesso a um `auth.jwt` para checar permissões na página.

Comment: cara, verifica esse link, ele tem exemplo de como possar informações via components:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/383927/enviar-id-via-componentes-independentes-a-partir-de-um-link-e-emiter-angular-2

Comment: já resolvi, obrigado

Comment: então coloca a resposta para nós. Para compartilhar com a galera.